# <h1> is not inheriting font-weight from its container

Tags: html, css, inheritance

I have a problem with inheritance in `CSS`. I made a `div` container put an `h1` element within it as such:

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
     <h1> test </h1>
   </div>
</body>
```

From what I understand, all text within the `h1` element is bold and has a font-weight of 2em. To counteract this, I placed the following `CSS` properties on the container.

```
.container{
     font-size:5em;
     font-weight:normal;
}
```

`h1` seems to inherit both properties and `h1`'s `font-size` changes to `5em` as expected. But `<h1>`'s font-weight stays bold, even though it inherited `font-weight:normal;` from its parent element. Here's what I see on my screen.

[image: Font-Weight Problem]

Why does the `h1`'s font-weight not change to `font-weight:normal;`? I'm think its because there are certain CSS properties, like font-weight, that a child element does not inherit from its parent.

```css
.container{
     font-size:5em;
     font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="container">
     <h1> test </h1>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How about `.container h1 { font-weight: inherit; }`?

Comment: Please check this link:-https://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade

Comment: I could, but why doesn't `<h1>` automatically inherit font-weight like it did for font-size? I didn't have to put an `font-size: inherit` for h1 .

Comment: Because the font size is actually twice what the container has (2em, which the browser adds), as for the font weight, it is explicitly assigned bold. So just target the h1 element and change the font-weight property.

Comment: The style inspector in devtools is showing you exactly what is happening, which is that user agent stylesheet is applying bold to `h1`.

Comment: The font-size is also not inherited. What you are seeing is 2em based on 5em (equally large as 10em if container had `font-size: 1em;`). Inheritance only applies to elements which have no other rule set for the property. Both `font-size` and `font-weight` have other property values defined in the user agent stylesheet.

Comment: Again, the font-size you see in your example is not 5em, but 5em * 2em = 10 em. `em` is calculated based on the font-size of the containing element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    I'm 8px text
    <h1>This is H1 in 16px font-size (8px * 2em = 16px)</h1>
</div>
```

`h1` neither inherits `font-size` nor `font-weight` because implicit inheritance only applies to *inherited* properties not defined *otherwise*.

What you are seeing is 2em based on 5em (equally large as 10em if container had `font-size: 1em;`).

Both `font-size` and `font-weight` have other property values defined in the *user agent stylesheet* as your dev tools are showing you.

For reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#inheriting

Answer (score 9):

This is a basic question relating to how the cascade works, how it relates to inheritance, and the user agent style sheet. Other answers contain hints of the correct answers, but could be confusing.

We define the cascade as the process of finding the value for each individual property on each specific element, based on rules whose selectors match that element, taking into account order, specificity, and importance. If no rule specifies a particular property, then that property takes on the **default** value. Note that this process does **not** include inheritance anywhere.

In other words, inheritance is not part of the cascade. Inheritance happens if and only if the property is inheritable, **and** the cascade results in no value for the propertly.

The CSS spec specifies that `font-weight` and `font-size` are inherited. This simply means that any element with no alternative rule for those properties will cause them to inherit the final, computed values from their parent.

But in this case, there **is** such a rule in the user agent style sheet for `h1`:

```
h1 { font-weight: bold; font-size: 2em; }
```

Therefore, unless there is a later matching rule with a selector of the same or greater specificity specifying these properties, or any matching rule with greater specificity, or any matching rule in which the property is marked `!important`, or a property is applied directly via the `style` attribute, then every single `h1` element on your page will be bold, and twice the size of its parent, since in this context `em` refers to the font-size of the parent. Note that inheritance does not figure into this calculation in any way whatsoever, since none of the property values are `inherit`. It is not that inheritance "tries" to happen and then is somehow overridden by the user-agent `h1` rule; it is that inheritance never happens in the first place.

For instance, the following rule

```
h1 { font-size: 5em; }
```

will override the `font-size` on `h1` elements specified in rules from the user agent style sheet, because this rule occurs "later" in the cascade than the rule from the user agent style sheet, and its selector has the same specificity. There is no need to mark this property declaration `!important`, as one answer suggested.

Note that giving your own rule of

```
* { font-size: 5em; }
```

would **not** override the `font-size` on `h1` elements specified in the user agent style sheet, since the selector `*` has lower specificity than the selector `h1`, even thought this rule comes later than the one from the user agent style sheet.

So far, then, the `font-size` on `h1` elements will be fixed to the size specified for `h1` in the user agent style sheet, or the size specified in your own rules if any, with no regard to inheritance.

Given the presence of the user agent style sheet rule for `h1`, the only way to cause `h1` elements to instead inherit their size, or weight, from their parent, is to specify the special value `inherit` for those properties, via the cascade, in rules which directly match the element in question. The only way to cause `h1` elements to have some other size or weight is to specify some other value for those properties in rules which directly match the element in question.

Hence, if we want the `h1` size and weight to inherit from its parent `.container`, we must explicitly say so by giving those properties a value of `inherit` in rules which directly apply to the `h1` elements:

```
.container h1 { font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit; }
```

If we want this behavior to pertain to **all** children of `.container`, then we could also write

```
.container * { font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit; }
```

If we want `h1` elements to have double the font size of their parent, well, that is the default behavior, since that is already what the `h1 { font-size: 2em; }` from the user agent style sheet says. Note that this is not inheritance per se; rather, it is the normal behavior of interpreting font size values of the form `2em` or `200%` in terms of the font size of the parent. Therefore

```
.container { font-size: 12px; }

<div class="container"><h1>Heading</h1></div>
```

will result in headings of `24px`.

But what if I really, really want to **force** inheritance downward onto a child? Could I not accomplish this by marking the property on the parent `!important`, as one other answer (incorrectly) suggests? No. `!important` only affects the cascade as it applies to determining the property value for the particular element(s) matching the selector. It does not somehow magically "strengthen" inheritance, or override some other setting on the children.

To summarize, in your particular case:

> Why does the `h1`'s font-weight not change to `font-weight: normal;`? I think it's because there are certain CSS properties, like `font-weight`, that a child element does not inherit from its parent.

As should be clear from the above, the `font-weight` for `h1` does not change to `font-weight: normal` (does not inherit) because `h1` has its own `font-weight` specified in the user agent style sheet. The `font-weight` property does indeed inherit, but only in the sense that `inherit` is its the **default** value, used only when no other rule specifying `font-weight` applies, which is not the case here.

If you want the `h1` to inherit directly from its parent, then the correct rule is

```
h1 { font-weight: inherit; }
```

or if you want that behavior only when it is inside the container, then

```
.container h1 { font-weight: inherit; }
```

This is probably better than

```
.container h1 { font-weight: normal; }
```

because it would allow you to change the weight of the container to anything you wanted, while ensuring that the weight of the child would follow suit. In terms of size, note that this will result in a size of double that of the container, because the user agent style sheet rule `h1 { font-size: 2em; }` still applies.

Comment: Very nice, comprehensive answer. Well done! I just hope OP is going to be willing to invest the time to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing, called user agent stylesheet. It is like a CSS file built into the browser. It contains the default properties of the HTML elements. You know, like why the background is white and the text is black by default.

The `<h1>` would inherit its parent's font-weight, because it is an inheritable property, but the user agent stylesheet overrides it.

You can see the default properties in the devtools.

Comment: It is not that the user agent stylesheet "overrides" anything; it **sets** the property's value, so that inheritance never occurs in the first place.